# Parsing a Pandas column in JSON format

Tags: json, pandas

I am parsing a Pandas column of type string that is in JSON format such as the following

```
kafka_data["MESSAGE_DATA__C"].iloc[0]
Out[20]: '{"userId":"af33f42e","trackingCategory":"ACTION","trackedItem":{"id":"PERSONAL_IDENTIFICATION_STARTED","category":"PERSONAL_IDENTIFICATION","title":"Personal Identification Started"}}'
```

When I parse a single row everything works

```
json.loads(kafka_data["MESSAGE_DATA__C"].iloc[0])
Out[25]: 
{'userId': 'af33f42e',
 'trackingCategory': 'ACTION',
 'trackedItem': {'id': 'PERSONAL_IDENTIFICATION_STARTED',
  'category': 'PERSONAL_IDENTIFICATION',
  'title': 'Personal Identification Started'}}
```

But when I try to parse altogether the column, an error prompts.

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 212 (char 211)
```

Am I missing anything?
I need to read this column into a new dataframe.

Comment: Does `kafka_data["MESSAGE_DATA__C"].apply(json.loads, axis=1)` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When applying a function to entire column, use `axis=1` parameter.

Please try:

```py
kafka_data[["MESSAGE_DATA__C"]].apply(lambda row: json.loads(str(row["MESSAGE_DATA__C"])), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I get this Type Error: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'`. Pandas version 1.4.3.
It seems like the series version of ´apply´ does not need the `axis` parameter.

Comment: Please try `kafka_data[["MESSAGE_DATA__C"]]` with double square brackets.

Comment: It runs into a different TypeError now: `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Series`

Comment: Convert to string using str() as mentioned in updated answer.

Comment: Hope that works! I'm not able to reproduce your problem. The above answer code is working for me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers. I have added another line of example at the end (line 1), because I get this sort of error `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 212 (char 211)`
I am hacking around too, I keep you posted once I solve it